# Oracle Golden gate setup for earlier versions of 10g such as 9i , 8i

Tags: database-design, relational-database, oracle-golden-gate

I need to set up oracle golden gate replication for Oracle DB earlier versions 9i , 8i. is it possible ? will golden gate support 8 and 9 .  Please provide details.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 10g - you can use GoldenGate 11.1 or 11.2.

For Oracle 9i - you can use GoldenGate 11.1.

For Oracle 8i - you probably need an earlier version of GoldenGate (10.4 or older). It is not more available, so you might need to request a build from Oracle.